# parallel processes in js

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, process, synchronization

I have one question about parallel processes in javascript. I mean async processes. I need play two soundtracks at the same time(sync). But, if I call it in a row, tracks can play a little bit async.:

```
audio.play();
audio2.play();
```

I think and I almost know, that javascript has opp. for processing async. actions. How?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would be to use the fantastic library called [async](https://github.com/caolan/async)

Then you could do

```
async.parallel([
    function(callback) { 
        audio.play();
        callback();
    },
    function(callback) {
        audio2.play();
        callback();
    }], function() {
          console.log("Both sounds running together");
});
```

Or I believe you can just wrap each .play like this

```
setTimeout(function() {
    audio.play();
});
setTimeout(function() {
    audio2.play();
});
```

Comment: `setTimeout` will add the function to the execution queue and execute the next task in the queue. However, when the time for `audio.play()` comes, you still have to execute it and block on it.

Answer (score 0):

Normally JS is considered to have a single thread of execution, meaning that it will *block* on a task until it has finished processing it. However, you can still do something to make it concurrent.

Beside the library that @Datsik has provided, I also would like to mention about **web worker** which is an API for *spawning background scripts in your web application*. However, you need browser support in order to successfully run web worker. Here is a convenient [website](http://caniuse.com/#feat=webworkers) for you to check your browser support for web worker. Also, here is another brief [introduction](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/) about web worker for your info. (If you would like to use web worker, you might have to refactor your code for a bit.)

Good luck!